# Wrong output of qDebug() (UTF - 8)

Tags: c++, qt, utf-8, qt4, qtcore

I'm trying to store a string with special chars::

```
qDebug() << "ÑABCgÓ";
```

Outputs: (here i can't even type the correct output some garbage is missing after Ã & Ã)
ÃABCgÃ

I suspect some UTF-8 / Latin1 / ASCII, but can't find the setting to output to console / file. What i have written in my code : "ÑABCgÓ".

(Qt:4.8.5 / Ubunto 12.04 / C++98)

Comment: I just tried qDebug() << "ÑABCgÓ" in a Qt program and the output is as expected. I'm using OSX, are you trying this with Windows?

Comment: Encoding it to base64 may be an alternative, depending what you want to do.

Comment: @Merlin069: I think it depends on the locale, so you are just lucky, so am I. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `QString QString::fromUtf8(const char * str, int size = -1) [static]` as the sample code presents that below. This is one of the main reasons why QString exists.

See the documentation for details:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qstring.html#fromUtf8

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    qDebug() << QString::fromUtf8("ÑABCgÓ");
    return 0;
}
```

#### Building (customize for your scenario)

```
g++ -fPIC -I/usr/include/qt -I/usr/include/qt/QtCore -lQt5Core main1000.cpp && ./a.out
```

#### Output

```
"ÑABCgÓ"
```

That being said, depending on your locale, simply `qDebug() << "ÑABCgÓ";` could work as well like in here, but it is recommended to make sure by explicitly asking the UTF-8 handling.

Comment: @KubaOber: ? C++11 was not mentioned by the OP, so we cannot assume it is available for sure, and strictly speaking: we cannot even assume Qt 5. My post works with Qt 4 as well as 5.

Comment: That's the whole point of `QStringLiteral`: it gives you benefits on C++11 while remaining compatible with C++98. For all I care you can have a version-check-wrapped `#define QStringLiteral(x) QString::fromUtf8(x)`, it'd be the most portable suggestion, and that's precisely what I do in my code.

Comment: No, actually QStringLiteral will not work fully without C++11. Variables passsed, hello? As I also said, QStringLiteral was only introduced in Qt 5, and in fact, it is even a bypass here. I do not understand what this thread has to do with QStringLiteral. It is about Utf 8 and Qt in general so far. That is exactly what QString::utf8() was designed for.

Comment: I quote from a woboq blog post: *QStringLiteral is a new macro introduced in Qt 5 to create QString from string literals. (String literals are strings inside "" included in the source code)*. I don't know what you mean by "variables passed", as the question was not about strings from variables, but from literals. The fact that QStringLiteral reverts to old behavior `#define QStringLiteral(str) QString::fromUtf8("" str "", sizeof(str) - 1)` on non-C++11 is what we want: code gains efficiency just by switching a compiler, yay!

Comment: @KubaOber: Except that, the literal might be stored in a QString. Again, you are making way too much assumption. Not to mention, you continuously disregard the fact that QStringLiteral was only introduced in Qt 5. More importantly, I am not sure what QStringLiteral has to do with the problem at hand, which is utf8. QStringLiteral is a generic macro for * any * string literal. That is why I think QStringLiteral is red herring in here. This is my last post in the thread before asking for the cleanup...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
 QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(codec);
 qDebug() << "ÑABCgÓ";
```

Comment: or use the "QString::fromUTF8" method

Comment: Do * not * use it. It is not available with Qt 5! It is creating uncertainty/bugs in using QString easily and (to a lesser extent) performance issues! I would suggest to delete this answer which goes against the Qt documentation. This should not be advertised.