# qt-qml-Qt Creator use msvc2017 qDebug print text messy

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, msvc12

I edit question here, the result is different between Visual Studio and Qt Creator:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/127597/qt-qml-qt-creator-use-msvc2017-qdebug-print-text-messy-on-windows7

Comment: Could be related to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183895/wrong-output-of-qdebug-utf-8

Comment: I try it, but the question remains, QStringLiteral, fromUtf8...